# Facebook Api getting feeds and comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the feeds on a public wall and the associated comments.
So every X minutes I'm doing a query in order to get what's new (feeds and comments).

I need the feeds (the new feeds since myDate) and comments (comments posted on the new  feeds and comments posted on older feeds).
So if someone posted a comment on a older feed I want to get it.
I tryied to do this using FQL and Graph API but I don't manage to find the best solution.

With FQL there are some problems (bugs) with LIMIT and OFFSET and does not work very well.
With the Graph API I don't have so much power.
So this is what I've tryied:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=MY_ACCES_TOKEN0&limit=500&since=1350033469&until=now&updated_time>1350033469
```

This gives me the newest post, so no problem because for each one I'm doing a new query in order to get the comments for each feed:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/comment?access_token=MY_ACCES_TOKEN0&limit=500&since=1350033469&until=now&updated_time>1350033469
```

The problem is that if a comment is posted on a older post, I don't receive it.

Using FQL I cannot filter only the newest posts (based on my since date) and the posts with new comments.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_id, text, fromid FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream where source_id=PAGE_ID and comments.created_date>1350033469)&access_token=MY_ACCES_TOKEN
```

Using Graph API I have a good pagination (using next and previous links inside the response) but with FQL I did't find any solution.

So anyone have some idea ?
Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API search using since updated\_time parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818119/facebook-graph-api-search-using-since-updated-time-parameter)

Answer (score 4):

First, the FQL is deprecating, so you need to use only the **Graph API**.

The solution that I came with, is that when you already have a post, you need to recheck the post with its unique ID, and that request gives you two times, `created_time` and `updated_time`, so you need to check if your `updated_time` changed.

The pagination given in the Graph API is for only posts, so when posts have new comments, they won't come first in the list, you need to find them yourself.

**-- UPDATE --**

Use `batch_requests` to achieve this, so you can make more requests at a time.

Comment: Your solution is not bad but what would you do if you have 5000 posts stored in DB. You will do 5000 queries to check the comments ?

Comment: I know, is terrible, we had more than that let me tell you, but you also have `batch_requests`, so you can querie like 1000 at a time, i don't really know the exact number, i used to do 60 at a time, because it was controllable.

Comment: I've read something about the batch request. So you're using it and it works fine?

Comment: of course, they are the same requests, only that you can do a lot of them at a time.

Comment: So, was this what you were looking for?

Comment: It's a compromise solution. I was hoping someone posting a second solution.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking FQL is not deprecating. Rest API is deprecating and if I undertand correctely is not the same thing.

Comment: Did you end up using batch requets? was this a solution for you?

Comment: Hey Guys.. Since FQL is deprecating now ( announced as part of Version 2.0) I need to find an answer to this issue. From my testing (a long time ago) it seemed that checking every post used up some of the API limit. That means the more Posts, the less often you can check. I would suggest with 5000 posts you may struggle to even check them all for comments would be limited to every 15 minutes? Can anyone explain how the API limiting affects this?.. Many thanks  Rob