# Get the new comments after a particular comment Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am getting Facebook posts and their comments from the facebook graph API (I cannot use FQL). I am able to save the posts and their comments successfully into my database. However, I am not able to get the new comments where are there on the post which I dont have in my tables. I tried

> postid/comments?time=2014-04-13T00:00:00+0000
>
> postid/comments?since=2014-04-13T00:00:00+0000
>
> postid/comments?since_id=001122334455

but it is still not giving me records after that date. I also referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860126/facebook-api-getting-feeds-and-comments) but it does not has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your time to a unix time stamp, then it should work.

For instance, the Unix timestamp for the time above is 1428935421

```
postid/comments?since=1428935421
```

http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: I tried since and until, both in unix time stamp format, still it gives result out of the specified date range